# Http request 400 error from a very simple POST request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build an Asp.Net app and I have a very straight forward http POST request that gives me a 400 error. I have cleared all my browsing data and flushed my local dns but the problem persists.

Request:`https://myurl.com/user/create?username=username&password=password`

I swear it worked yesterday but when I booted it up today to look at it now it's broken. I'm not missing some simple syntax mistake am I?